# Simulating keystrokes on a background process using C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to simulate keystrokes on a certain game **(while its window is not focused)**, which will make my character move as I tell him.
I've tried to use :

**PostMessage(Process.GetProcessById(PID).MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x2d, 0x1520001);**

Which works just fine with INSERT key. However, when trying to simulate arrow keys (right key):

**PostMessage(Process.GetProcessById(PID).MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x27, 0x14d0001);**

It doesnt work how I expect it to. My character does not move, but when I focus the chat box **ingame** (while the game itself is **not** focused) I can see the marker moving right in the chatbox.

***Note:** I am able to simulate arrow keys using InputSimulator class:

**InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.RIGHT);**

^ works great for moving my character / using the chat box, but the only problem is that for SimulateKeyDown to work, the specific window has to be focused, which is not what I'm looking for.

I have been searching for a while now and failed to find an answer, I hope somebody here will help me figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is most probably about posting the message to wrong process id. Depending on the game, the main play screen may have a different PID than its .exe file, while the chatbox may be an in-app component. Have you tried using Spy++ to get the PID of the main screen?

Comment: Oh. you're programming a bot. I'm curious for the answers now

Comment: @Nail first of all, thanks for the quick answer. Second, I have checked and it is the same window for both the chatbox and the game itself. Also, how otherwise would you explain my character moving when using InputSimulator?

Comment: The main game.exe file will probably send all keystrokes to the game window, I think that's why your tests with InputSimulator was successful only when the game is focused. But if this is right, why doesn't it send the keystrokes sent by PostMessage() to the game window again? I am not really sure now.

Comment: @Nail using PostMessage() with the 'INSERT' key (0x2d) works fine but when trying PostMessage() with the right arrow key (0x27) it doesnt react. However, they both work the same inside the checkbox(when it is focused) but when it is not focused, only the insert key works. I do believe it has something to do with the wParam, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try posting key events in Down/Up combinations. Example:

```
PostMessage(Process.GetProcessById(PID).MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, ...);
PostMessage(Process.GetProcessById(PID).MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, ...);
// Or use a single PostMessage call with a combination of KEYDOWN/KEYUP flags.

InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.RIGHT);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.RIGHT);
```

Comment: That doesn't work for the arrow keys. For anything other than the arrow keys it does work

Comment: I see you've already tried Spy++. Consider using the Win32 EnumWindows and EnumChildWindows to see if you can get to the target control. Also Spy++ has a feature that not only let's you visually locate child classes but can attach to the main window and log the message pump. That may be worth monitoring if you have the game in focus and send actual arrow keys (not simulated).